# Using OpenCV in a Windows phone 8 application

Tags: opencv, windows-phone-8

I need to use **OpenCV** in my project for **Windows phone 8**. I can't find any compiled version of openCV for wp8. Any idea? Can I compile the source for wp8?

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an older question, but it still shows up on Google when I search for "Windows Phone 8 opnecv".  A recent Github project has been released (includes samples too!) that can be used with Windows Phone 8 --> https://github.com/MSOpenTech/opencv.  It was originally announced here --> http://msopentech.com/blog/2014/03/20/easily-build-opencv-powered-apps-for-windows-store/